# Ruby - Accessing class that is not in the current scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 classes

`MyController` which is under `app/controllers/api`

`MyManager` which is under `libs/managers`

I am trying to use this manager class from my controller and I'm getting the following error.

**Uninitialized constant API::MyController::MyManager**

How do I reference and use MyManager class from MyController class?

Controller

```
class API::MyController < API::BaseController
  before_action :setup

  def something
    @myManager.doSomething
  end

  def setup
    # Exception is thrown here
    @myManager = MyManager.new
  end

end
```

Manager

```
class MyManager
   def doSomething
      puts('something')
   end
end
```

Comment: Extra information (sample of code with both files definitions and constant use context) would be usefull. Basically it seems like a problem of initialization order, but for now it's just a guess.

Comment: @Meredian Added sample code

Comment: Didn't first answer and referencing `::MyManager` instead of `MyManager` helped?

Comment: @Meredian No that didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you autoloaded the lib/managers directory:

```
# in config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/managers)
```

If MyManager is a Class (not a module) then you can just call MyManager.new without any problem.

Also just a note.  In Rails 4 there are a couple of 'concerns' directories added under app/controllers and app/models (app/controllers/concerns and app/models/concerns).  Any files under these directories will be autoloaded.  By standards, only model related concerns (be it modules or classes) will be placed under app/models/concerns (same applies for controller related concerns).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way rails loads modules, take a look at [this](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/)

I think what you want is to make sure your autoloading the lib directory and then call `::MyManager.method` since its trying to get the module from the Controller context.

`::Module` indicates the absolute module.